# Using non-static code with static main method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm having trouble with getting my static main method to play nicely with my backend code.

Here's the backend stuff:

```
public interface ITicketGenerationService
{
    string CreateTicket(DateTime begin, DateTime end);       
}

public class TicketGenerationService : ITicketGenerationService
{
    public static IRepository<Ticket> Repository { get; set; }

    public TicketGenerationService(IRepository<Ticket> repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    public string CreateTicket(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
    {
         //do stuff with Repository
         //return status string to Main method
    }

}
```

Here's where my console application begins:

```
public class TicketMain
{
    public ITicketGenerationService TicketGenerationService { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          var priorityOneTickets = TicketGenerationService.CreateTicket(begin, end);
    }
}
```

So I initially get this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'TicketMain.TicketGenerationService'

If I change CreateTicket to static, I get another error:

> TicketGenerationService does not implment interface member
>   ITicketGenerationService.CreateTicket(DateTime, DateTime).
>   ITicketGenerationService.CreateTicket(DateTime, DateTime) cannot
>   implement an interface member because it is static.

If I try to add this:

> var ticketingService = new TicketGenerationService();

to the main method, I'm afraid that will mess with my dependency injection(autofac).

I understand the errors, but I can't make everything static, and I'm afraid if I start instantiating, I'll lose all my data I gain via dependency injection.

Is there anyway around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the `TicketGenerationService.CreateTicket` method that the error is referring to, it's your `TicketGenerationService` property in the `TicketMain` class.

You just need to change your property to `static`:

```
public static ITicketGenerationService TicketGenerationService { get; set; }
```